# What reverse connector do I need for Nikon?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, macro, reverse-mount

I have 2 lenses for my Nikon D7000. First is 18-55mm and 18-200mm.
I saw some pictures on internet are done using some reverse connector to get macro effect.
What exactly I need to buy and how exactly to attach (18-55 to body or 18-200 to body) everything to each other in order to get "cheap macro"?

Update: 
From the local online market I've found this ring, please let me know if I can use it and how.

[image]

Comment: I guess it is worth to mention that both are G lenses. Also I'm not sure how to manually set the aperture, because there CPU is not connected to lens.

Comment: So there is no way to change aperture size with both lenses manually, means I can forget about cheap macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reversing ring with a 52mm thread on one side and a standard Nikon lens mount on the other. You screw the reversing ring thread onto the filter thread at the end of the lens, then attach the lens-mount side to the camera body. You would do this with your 18-55mm lens because:

**A)** I believe the 18-200 has a 72mm filter size and

**B)** A wider angle lens gives greater magnification when reversed, so the 200mm is unnecessary anyway.

As your lens does not have a manual aperture ring, you will need to hold the aperture lever open at the exposed end of the lens (the end that is normally attached to the camera), either with your finger or with a blob of poster tack. You then set your camera to manual mode to start taking photos, as this mode ignores the lack of a CPU connection.

See the Photography StackExchange Blog post on reversing rings which tells you everything you need to know to get started, [here](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/take-macro-shots-like-this-for-less-than-the-cost-of-a-pizza/).

Answer (score 3):

Actually instead of holding the apeture lever or using an aftermarket adapter you can use your DOF preview button or live view when the lens is connected properly. Then without shutting the camera off, pop the lens off and your apeture should stay where you had it set while it was connected properly. Much easier and I have used this trick with a d3100, d5100, d800 and the d3x. Works everytime without flaw.